# Ubuntu 13.04 wired connection is not working

Tags: networking, 13.04, wired

After upgrading to 13.04 I can't make wired connection work (wireless internet works fine). I checked in connection settings that it's supposed to connect automatically.

ifconfig gives:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:e0:b7:4e:4e:55
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:c0700000-c0720000 

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:699 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:699 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:87573 (87.5 KB)  TX bytes:87573 (87.5 KB)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:b7:0d:96:e9:52  
      inet6 addr: fe80::9eb7:dff:fe96:e952/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4889 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2250 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1909434 (1.9 MB)  TX bytes:339972 (339.9 KB)
```

lshw -C network:

```
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 04
   serial: e8:e0:b7:4e:4e:55
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi cap_list ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=e1000e latency=0 multicast=yes
   resources: irq:20 memory:c0700000-c071ffff memory:c072b000-c072bfff ioport:2080(size=32)
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 9c:b7:0d:96:e9:52
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.8.0-19-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.8.134 
     latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:18 memory:c0500000-c050ffff
```

and lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) 
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
03:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
```

The only solution that kind of worked for me (which I found in similar questions to previous releases) was adding to /etc/network/interfaces the following lines.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

But then whenever I boot without wired connection I get problems with network configuration and have to wait a long time before the system starts.

I understand that the problem is with my e1000e driver (correct?) but I'm not really sure what I could do about it. I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You might try the technique in posts #25 and following: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2050514&page=3

Comment: chili555, many thanks for your reply. The solution works for me. Apologies for not finding it on my own and once again thank you!

Comment: Glad it's working! Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`echo on | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eth0/device/power/control`

This should definitely solve the whole problem...after its done, exit sudo and pull out, then plug in the ethernet cable again